# I am working on AWs IAM role, Where I am using two roles , the first role was assume by second role, I want run that role more than 2 hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I wanted to use the temporary session to run that role for more than 2 hours
but getting an error as the session expired because of chaning

I tried to run that but getting a token expired error as credential can be valid for only 1 hour

How can I achieve running role credentials more than 2 hours without a session expire error?

Comment: You need to assume the role again and again and again...

Comment: thanks for your reply. In what way  I can do that can you explain?

Comment: Either the same way you originally assumed the second role or you could attempt to configure the second role to be able to assume itself.

Comment: Two hours? When you use role chaining, your new credentials are limited to a maximum duration of one hour.

Comment: If you use IRSA you can create an OIDC endpoint for your cluster in a different account than your cluster and assume a role in that account. ISRA will renew your credentials automatically.

Comment: Yes, its 1 hour. but How can I increase that?